# A way to piggy back onto ng-bind?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that resizes text in a box to always keep it on one line. It works really well when the text inside comes from the server, but now I'm trying to use it for dynamic text generated by my angular controller and it's not updating when the text populates. Does anybody know of a way to piggy back on all of the watches that ng-bind sets up behind the scenes?

My directive is called textToFill, so ideally I would like to be able to watch the contents whether it be bound by `ng-bind` or through interpolation.

```
<div text-to-fill ng-bind="testText"></div>
<div text-to-fill>{{ testText }}</div>
```

Anybody know if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

very simply put I would create a watch expression inside the link function of my directive that watches attrs.ng-bind and then reapplies the text resizing based on that.

Comment: This won't work for interpolation which would be fine except it won't even work for something like `ng-bind="testText + ' ' + testText2"`

Comment: I mean it could... you would just get the literal value and and then split to reveal an array of values in this case testText testText2 and then you would watch an array of expressions for changes and then apply your text morphing

Comment: also if you were really lazy and performance wasn't a total issue you could watch for changes on the entire scope and then apply your changes if they are light weight enough. $scope.$watch(function() { }); whatever function you execute could be throttled using underscore so that it doesn't fire too many times per second.